# Копирование изображений из mssql в mysql с помощью PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, blob

Провожу рефакторинг кода сайта на `PHP`. Код был перенесен с `CentOS 6`, `PHP 5.3`, `mysql 5.1.73` на `Ubuntu 16.04`, `php 7.0`, `mysql 5.7.17`.
Соответственно из-за перехода на `PHP 7.0` пришлось менять код. А конкретнее - методы работы с БД - `mysql` на `PDO`. Все получилось, и все работает хорошо.

Два раза в неделю необходимо производить обмен данными между базой данных сайта и базой данных менеджеров(`Microsoft SQL Server 2005`).

Если коротко, то `CLI` скрипт просто отчищает таблицу в `mysql` базе, а за тем копирует в нее данные из mssql базы.

Вот пример:

```
<?php

try {

    $host = "localhost";
    $site_db = "site_db";
    $user = "root";
    $password = '12345';

    $mysql = new PDO ("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$site_db","$user","$password" );

    $mysql->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    print_r( $e->getMessage() );
    exit;

}

try {

    $host = "192.168.0.34";
    $port = 1433;
    $manager_db = "manager_db";
    $user = "admin";
    $password = '12345';

    $mssql = new PDO ("dblib:host=$host:$port;dbname=$manager_db","$user","$password" );

    $mssql->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $mssql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    print_r( $e->getMessage() );
    exit;

}

$mysql -> query( 'TRUNCATE firms' );

$mssql_query = $mssql -> prepare("
    SELECT firm_id, firm_name, address, image  FROM firms
");

$mssql_query->execute();

while( $row = $mssql_query -> fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){

    foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) {

        if ( $key !== 'image' ) {
            $row[$key] = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $row[$key]);
        }

    }

    $mysql_query = $mysql -> prepare("

        INSERT INTO 
            `firms` ( firm_id, firm_name, address, image ) 
        VALUES 
            ( ?, ?, ?, ? )

    ");

    $mysql_query -> execute( array(

        $row['firm_id'],
        $row['firm_name'],
        $row['address'],
        $row['image']

    ) );

    if ( !$mysql_query ) {
        print_r( $mysql_query->error );
        break;   
    }
}
```

Но закралась одна проблема. После копирования, размер двоичных данных в поле `image` в базе данных `mysql` не превышают 64 килобайт. Бывает и меньше, но порог в 64 килобайта не превышается. При попытке скачать изображение из базы, средствами `phpMyAdmin` изображение скачивается и даже открывается, но оно обрезанное.

Для примера:
- Слева - изображение скопированное из `mssql` базы в `mysql` базу. Размер 64 512 байт.
-Справа - исходное изображение в `mssql` базе. Размер 87 047 байт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До рефакторинга все нормально работало.

Тип поля `image в mssql - image`. 
Тип поля `image в mysql - MEDIUMBLOB`

То есть проблема не в таблицах а скорее всего в методе работы с БД - `PDO`.

Затем узнал о `bindColumn`, `bindParam` и `PDO::PARAM_LOB`, но после применения результат тот же. Еще я выяснил, что изображения приходят из базы `mssql` уже обрезанные. То есть изображения обрезаются не на этпе записи в `mysql`, а на этапе выборки из `mssql`. Уже неделю ковыряюсь в интернете и ничего не нахожу толкового. Товарищи, нужна Ваша помощь!

Comment: обрезанное в смысле битое? зы: для этой процедуры вообще пхп обязательно использовать, т.е. не является ли это лишним звеном? я в целом про Linked Servers или integration services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немножко погуглил и нашёл такое обсуждение:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38805

Предлагается несколько вариантов, кто-то пишет что всё рабоатет, кто-то до сих пор страдает.

Попробуйте

```
$pdo->query('SET TEXTSIZE 300000');
```

или

```
SELECT CONVERT(TEXT,field) as field_name from table
```

При выборке данных. Или оба варианта - вдруг поможет)

Comment: Спасибо! $pdo->query('SET TEXTSIZE 300000'); помогло. Не думал, что это какой-то баг.

Comment: Отметьте тогда как правильный ответ :)